# Cordova app - Use ringer volume instead of media in Android

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova, ant

I'm using Cordova v4.1.2. The app uses media volume by default, and I want it to use the ringer volume for the sounds it plays. (Like in WhatsApp)

I used `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);`in the onCreate() function. But it gives an error.

This is my CordovaApp.java. (in platforms\android\src\com\XX\XX)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
    }
}
```

It shows the following error on running:

[image]

There is no error when I remove the line `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);` from the java file, and the app runs perfectly. Any views on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it myself. Really easy if you were an Android geek, but anyways such a question was never asked before so I'll post the answer for others running into this same trouble.

I was right in changing the audio stream, but I was changing that in the wrong file! Doh!

This is where you should change it..

```
\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaActivity.java
```

at line 351 change it to `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);`

If you want to use the ringer volume though.

If you build and press the hardware volume keys, it will change and appear to use the ringer volume of course. But my case was a bit different.

I was using the cordova Media plugin [org.apache.cordova.media](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media). So when I play an audio using this plugin, it re-wires the stream back to media stream (STREAM_MUSIC). I was back to ground zero. The idea is to re-wire the plugin itself to use the audio stream of your choice. No rocket science, just change 2 lines in 2 files.

File:

```
\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\media\AndroidHandler.java
```

Line 383:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

File:

```
\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\media\AudioPlayer.java
```

Line 526:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

And you're good to go. Remember to replace STREAM_RING with your desired audio stream.

Comment: Any chance that this could be made into a plugin?

Comment: Note that in the latest version of the Media plugin, the plugin file is AudioHandler.java, method name onFirstPlayerCreated, currently at line number 468. It sets the VolumeControlStream when the first player is created, and resets it back to the previous one when the last player has been released.

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me. It's still using the "Media" source when the sound is adjusted while playing.